# Ignore or remove duplicate tags

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a small program that takes in html tags and then determines if the two sets of tags\attributes passed are the same or not.

This code works:

```
def tags_equal(str1, str2):
    a = list(str1[1:-1].lower().split())
    a.sort()
    b = list(str2[1:-1].lower().split())
    b.sort()
    x = (a == b)
    return x


print(tags_equal("<img src=cats.jpg width=200 height=400>", "<IMG SRC=Cats.JPG height=400 width=200>"))
print(tags_equal("<img src=dogs.jpg width=999 height=400>", "<img src=dogs.jpg width=200 height=400>"))
print(tags_equal("<p>", "<P>"))
print(tags_equal("<b>", "<p>"))
```

This correctly returns:  True, False, True and False.

There is an option that states if duplicate attributes are passed in, then the first one is the one that is to be used and all other attributes with the same
name are to be ignored.

This means:

```
tags_equal("<LABEL FOR=id_email for=id_username>", "<LABEL FOR=id_email>")
```

should return 'True', as 'for=id_username' is ignored\dropped, and

```
tags_equal("<LABEL FOR=id_email for=id_username>", "<LABEL FOR=id_username>")
```

should return 'False'.

I'm simply stuck as to how to proceed.  Also, there could be more than two attributes with the same name passed in.  If so, then the first one stays ad all others are dropped\ignored.

Lastly, the 'first one wins' is based upon the passed in order, not the post sort order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Casting everything to lowercase looks like a bad idea to me. On a Windows machine `img=cat.jpg` and `img=CAT.JPG` may the same, but on a linux machine they're not.

Comment: Also, applying a sort seems to be counter-productive for what you want.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, if I use the following, the first of my four tests incorrectly returns False:  ```def tags_equal(str1, str2):
    a = str1[1:-1]
    b = str2[1:-1]
    x = (a.casefold() == b.casefold())
    return x```    That's why I sort the data.

Comment: Looks like good use of a dictionary to grab tags as keys and doing a check if the tag exists before adding it to the dictionary

Comment: @Easton Bornemeier, how would you separate the tag from the rest of the input data?  Regex?

Comment: Try [BeautifulSoup](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)